# NestJS websockets - Get client URL and hostname

Tags: node.js, websocket, nestjs

I am trying to access the hostname of a client in NestJS websockets when a message is received. I have searched here, NestJS docs, and the project Github issues & code but have not found a solution.

I have tried accessing properties on the client object, but the hostname is not included. I was able to find it in the handleConnection subscriber, but I need it in the SubscribeMessage handler.

Would love any help!

Sample of the code from the docs:

```js
export class SessionsGateway
  implements OnGatewayConnection, OnGatewayDisconnect
{
  constructor() {}

  async handleDisconnect() {}

  async afterInit(server) {}

  @SubscribeMessage('init')
  async onInit(
    @MessageBody() event,
    @ConnectedSocket() client,
  ) {
    try {
      // GET THE HOSTNAME HERE
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      client.close();
    }
  }
```

Comment: Is the value of `client.handshake.headers` *undefined*?

Comment: indeed, `handshake` itself is undefined inside the `client` object

Comment: It's strange! I've tested on my project, and even with Nest.js [sample](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/tree/master/sample/02-gateways), and I had the header's value. Which version of packages are you using?

Comment: Inside the message handler? (my onInit function).. might be because I'm using localhost and it doesn't have an handshake??

Comment: hmm, I've tested on local with Postman, and it was fine.